# Mean and Variance of Linearity of the expectation operator

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

If $X$ is a variable with mean $M_x$ and variance $V_x$ then what is the mean, variance and mean square for $Y=aX+b?$
Here, $a$ is scaling factor and $b$ is constant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Show your effort?

Comment: If it was Y=aX, I should have wrote the expectation of Y will be "a" times of expectation of X. But here is a constant also. However, The expected value of a constant is the constant itself. But this thing I could not understand and consequently I could not calculate the mean, variance and mean square.

Comment: Expectation is a linear operator. Expectation of sum is sum of expectations

Comment: @ E M Tony Have a look at this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240132/prove-eax-b-aex-b/240134#240134

Comment: I have calculated the expected value. But still struggling with the mean, variance and mean square. Is it correct that the mean and variance are the "a" times the mean of X?